# Gmail V5.0.1 crashes sending an attachment

Tags: android, gmail

I have two apps that attach multiple CSV files to an email and send it to an email address of the users choosing.  I have a Nexus 4 phone for testing mobile and an Acer A500 for testing tablet.

My problem is that I updated the Gmail on the phone to V5.0.1.  Now, gmail crashes when trying to send the CSV attachments.  However, on the tablet with Gmail V4.2.1 it sends the attachments perfectly well.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: is this code related?

Comment: The code works on both devices until sending an attachment.  Gmail will open and attempt to send the attachments.  Gmail V5.0.1 crashes but Gmail V5.0.1 works and sends the attachments.

Comment: User bug on closed source app cannot be answered here.

Comment: Nothing shows in the log.